# Save password in firefox per script

Tags: firefox

I want to add passwords into firefox. 
Unfortunately I haven't found a function yet to import a CSV database.
Is there a built in function or a possibility to store a user and a password for a specific target?

Comment: You could use this opportunity to use a password manager - this would be a lot safer than saving passwords in firefox. Keepass, for example, allow importing CSV and can directly integrate into firefox via KeeFox. Let me know if that sounds suitable and I'll type up a detailed answer.

Comment: Yeh. You're right. But my goal is to not install any other software on my clients. Image you got 100 clients and you don't want to install other software to manage proxy settings with a user. I got firefox version 60 and suitable GPOs. Unfortunately I can't add a user and a suitable password. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Are you trying to manage proxy settings or are you trying to import a CSV file with credentials onto these clients? The latter sounds like extremely bad practice.